# How I can convert a multipart file into the file in java

Tags: java, postman, multipartform-data

I am upload a file from post man and send a request to my api using POST method and i am using Content-Type as multipart/form-data so I am receiving a binay data in the json body as :

```
"body-json": "MS4KCkZvciBzZWN1cml0eSByZWFzb24gbXlzcWwgLXUgcm9vdCB3b250IHdvcmsgdW50aWxsIHlvdSBwYXNzIC1wIGluIGNvbW1hbmQgc28gdHJ5IHdpdGggYmVsb3cgd2F5CgogbXlzcWwgLXUgcm9vdCAtcFtFbnRlcl0K",
```

Now my Question is that how I can conver this data into my exactly same file as I uploaded on post man with it's original content.

please help me soon till evening.

Comment: likely, the multipart/form-data is what you upload, not what the server sends back. This is more likely application/json, although what you have shown is not valid JSON.

Comment: https://g1z5rolmj7.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/test/uploadfile

Comment: Please export your postman call and post it here. Please also specify which web framework you are using to write your Java code (name and version - e.g. Servlet 2.4).

Comment: Method seected from postman is POST.   And URL as https://g1z5rolmj7.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/test/uploadfile       I pass Key as Content-Type and it's value is as: multipart/form-data  in Header      And Then upload a txt file and then press ok.      Now I am checking log where i have like this:         "body-json": "MS4KCkZvciBzZWN1cml0eSByZWFzb24gbXlzcWwgLXUgcm9vdCB3b250IHdvcmsgdW50aWxsIHlvdSBwYXNzIC1wIGluIGNvbW1hbmQgc28gdHJ5IHdpdGggYmVsb3cgd2F5CgogbXlzcWwgLXUgcm9vdCAtcFtFbnRlcl0K",
How Can i Convert this Json to MY uploaded file

Comment: Trace Entry ~ Class Name ~ UploadFileToS3Handler,~ Method Name ~createPublishEntity,~ Data ~
{ "body-json": "MS4KCkZvciBzZWN1cml0eSByZWFzb24gbXlzcWwgLXUgcm9vdCB3b250IHdvcmsgdW50aWxsIHlvdSBwYXNzIC1wIGluIGNvbW1hbmQgc28gdHJ5IHdpdGggYmVsb3cgd2F5CgogbXlzcWwgLXUgcm9vdCAtcFtFbnRlcl0K",
    "params": {  "content-type": "multipart/form-data","Host": "g1z5rolmj7.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com",
        }
    },  "api-id": "g1z5rolmj7", "http-method": "POST","resource-path": "/uploadfile"
    } this is my log

Comment: Edit your question, don't post question content in comment